# Integrate $\sin (x+y) =\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $\sin (x+y) =\frac{dy}{dx}.$

Let $x+y = t$, then differentiate w.r.t. $x$, we get $1+\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dt}{dx}$.

Afterward what we have to do?

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin  (x+y)=\frac { dy }{ dx } \\ x+y=t\\ y=t-x\\ \frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { dt }{ dx } -1\\ \sin { t= } \frac { dt }{ dx } -1\\ \sin { t+1 } =\frac { dt }{ dx } \\ \int { \frac { dt }{ \sin { t } +1 }  } =\int { dx } $$ 
Can you take from here?

Answer (score 0):

dy/dx= dt/dx - 1
Putting in ques. sin t = dt/dx - 1 
dt/dx = sin t +1
dt/sin t +1 = dx
Integrating we get 
1- sin t/( 1-sin^2 t) = dx
1- sin t/ cos^2 r = dx
Separate divide
(sec^2 t) -(tan t•sec t) =dx
Integrate 
tan t - sec t +C = x
tan  (x+y) - sec (x+y) +C =x  ________ans. ..

Comment: Your equations are very difficult to understand. You should use latex/mathjax.